# Data set not showing in html

Tags: angular

I have the following data set which I am trying to display in my HTML.

```
[{
  "InvestmentStrategy": {
    "name": [
      "Lifestage",
      "Shari'ah",
      "Comprehensive"
    ]
  },
  "RiskRating": {
    "name": [
      "Conservative",
      "Moderate",
      "Aggresive"
    ]
  },
  "Management": {
    "name": [
      "Active",
      "Passive"
    ]
  }
}]

<div *ngFor="let i of portfolioSelection.InvestmentStrategy">
  {{ i.name }}
</div>
```

portfolioSelection is the whole data set as seen above.
I only want to display the InvestmentStrategy names but currently get the following error
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'InvestmentStrategy' of undefined*

Comment: you are trying to access property of a object which is inside an array, so the syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access property of an object which is inside an array so you need to do the following :

```
portfolioSelection = [{
  "InvestmentStrategy": {
    "name": [
      "Lifestage",
      "Shari'ah",
      "Comprehensive"
    ]
  },
  "RiskRating": {
    "name": [
      "Conservative",
      "Moderate",
      "Aggresive"
    ]
  },
  "Management": {
    "name": [
      "Active",
      "Passive"
    ]
  }
}]

<div *ngFor="let item of portfolioSelection">
  <div *ngFor="let x of item?.InvestmentStrategy?.name">
   {{ x }}
  </div>
</div>
```